# Saving code files locally from different Git Remote URLs using python

Tags: python, git

I want to grab code of a single file from a Remote Git URL and save it locally, for example:

https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/58c4582f15ad01e1de33fb8857d131d51df514e9/apntool/apntool.py

or

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/stash-example-plugin/src/master/src/main/java/com/atlassian/stash/plugin/servlet/AccountServlet.java

I want to do this using python. Is there a way to do this without having to pull down & clone the entire repository?

I can use a python wget for 'Raw' files for each:

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/58c4582f15ad01e1de33fb8857d131d51df514e9/apntool/apntool.py`

or

`wget https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/stash-example-plugin/raw/a6e5e7d797edf751cbd839d6bd4aef86c941eec9/src/main/java/com/atlassian/stash/plugin/servlet/AccountServlet.java`

However as you can see, they're coming from two different Git Remote platforms.  If I'm only given the original URLs (and not the Raw URLs), then there's no standardised way of getting to the Raw versions of the URLs from different platforms.

I've been reading through GitPython which seems overkill - I've only seen it clone entire repositories to get access to its files.

I'm probably overcomplicating, but is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how raw github and bitbucket urls are formatted:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo-name>/<branch-name>/<file-name>
https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo-name>/raw/<branch-name>/<file-name>
```

So you can simply do some link hacking to fetch the url:

```
github_url = 'https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/58c4582f15ad01e1de33fb8857d131d51df514e9/apntool/apntool.py'
github_url = github_url.replace('github.com', 'raw.githubusercontent.com').replace('blob/58c4582f15ad01e1de33fb8857d131d51df514e9', 'master', 1)
!wget {github_url}

bitbucket_url = 'https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/stash-example-plugin/src/master/src/main/java/com/atlassian/stash/plugin/servlet/AccountServlet.java'
bitbucket_url = bitbucket_url.replace('/src/', '/raw/', 1)
!wget {bitbucket_url}
```

Comment: Thank you for this - the only issue with this is that I'd have to have each Git platform hard-coded for whichever one the URL relates to